# JavaScript String Format Not Working

Tags: javascript, string, format

I'm trying to create a string format I have about 8 parameters. 
I want to do something like this shown below.

```
string.format("www.website.com?Id={0}&Name={1}", 2,Emma)
```

However I have tried in JavaScript and it doesn't work.

Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because that's *not* a standard JavaScript function. One can't make up stuff and expect it work. Instead of blaming JavaScript ("Not Working"), start by searching for how to do the indented task and/or what the "Not Working" error (in the console) means.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** `format()` method for Javascript string objects.

However, you can easily implement it yourself using the code provided by fearphage: [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/4673436#4673436)

Answer (score 0):

Supporting `String.prototype.format()`:

```js
String.prototype.format = function(){
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(a, num){
    return args[num] || a
  })
}

var str = "www.website.com?Id={0}&Name={1}".format(2, "Emma");
alert(str)
```

If you are in an environment with [**ECMAScript ES6's**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) support, you can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
var variables = [2, "Emma"];
var str = `www.website.com?Id=${variables[0]}&Name=${variables[1]}`;
```